# Select an id that ends with something inside a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="abcdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="defdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="ijkdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="notthisone">No div</div>
</div>
<div id="xyzdiv">No div</div>
```

I need to select only the divs that ends with the id `"div"` and also only those that are inside `<div id="mydiv">`

In this case, my output should be only the following divs

```
<div id="abcdiv">yes div</div>
<div id="defdiv">yes div</div>
<div id="ijkdiv">yes div</div>
```

and not

```
<div id="notthisone">No div</div> and <div id="xyzdiv">No div</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`attribute ends with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) at this context,

```
var elem = $("#mydiv div[id$='div']");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4x8h0c2y/)

And that above selector is a valid css selector too. You can use it in css also.

```
#mydiv div[id$='div'] {
 color : red;
}
```

But note that this selector will use regex under the hood. That may drain the performance when you are running this selector in a dom with 100+ elements. So the better approach would be using a class to distinguish the required element from the others. Like,

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="abcdiv" class="yes">yes div</div>
    <div id="defdiv" class="yes">yes div</div>
    <div id="ijkdiv" class="yes">yes div</div>
    <div id="notthisone">No div</div>
</div>
```

And the selector will be like,

```
#mydiv div.yes {
 color :red;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `[attr$=value]` [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is suffixed by "value".

```css
#mydiv div[id$="div"] {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="abcdiv">yes div</div>
  <div id="defdiv">yes div</div>
  <div id="ijkdiv">yes div</div>
  <div id="notthisone">No div</div>
</div>
<div id="xyzdiv">No div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div#mydiv div[id$=div]` matches all of your criteria :

- The element must be inside a `<div>` with id `mydiv`
- The element must be a `<div>` itself
- The id of the element must end with `div`

---

#### Demo

```css
div#mydiv div[id$=div] {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="abcdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="defdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="ijkdiv">yes div</div>
    <div id="notthisone">No div</div>
    <section id="notadiv">Not a div</section>
    <section id="notadiv">
       Also not a div
       <div id="inceptiondiv">inception</div>
    </section>
</div>
<div id="xyzdiv">No div</div>
```